# How to mock global Object with Jest in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the function:

```
const someFn = () => {
  const keys = Object.keys(someObj);
  // rest of function
}
```

In my unit test (with jest), I want to mock the return value of `Object.keys`:

```
test('some test', () => {
  jest.mocked(Object.keys).mockReturnValue(['one', 'two']);
  // rest of test
});
```

But that resulting the following error:

```
TypeError: jest.mocked(...).mockReturnValue is not a function
```

Usually It means that I need to first mock the export itself using `jest.mock`, but with global `Object` I'm not sure how to do it. I thought maybe:

```
global.Object = {
  keys: jest.fn(),
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work at all.

Any idea how to solve this issue? thanks :)

Comment: You'd better mock `someObj` instead of mocking `Object.keys`, the later will change the behavior of all modules you are using, even `jest` itself.